# switching the expected input from string to bool

Tags: ocaml

Having the task:
Write a function `printmat : bool array array -> unit = <fun>` that
given a bool matrix it prints it on screen with ones and zeros, instead of
true and false.

```ml
    # let matrix =[|[| false ; true ; false |];[| true ; false ; false
    |];[| false ; false ; true |];[| false ; false ; false |]|];;
     # printmat matrix ;;
     010
     100
     001
     000
```

I managed to do this so far:

```ml
    let matrix = [|
      [|true; true; false; false|];
      [|false; false; true; true|];
      [|true; false; true; false|];
      [|true; false; false; true|]
    |];;
    let print_s matrix =
      let n = Array.length matrix in
      for i = 0 to n - 1 do
        let n1 = Array.length matrix in
        for j = 0 to n1 - 1 do
          print_string matrix.(i).(j);
        done;
        print_string"/n";
      done;;
```

But, my function has a type `string array array` instead of `bool array array`. It is also affecting the calling of the function since my code only works for the already declared matrix, I can't call a function with the given matrix since it expects bool type.

Comment: If you use `print_string` in your function of course it expects a string array array instead of a bool.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [`Printf`](https://ocaml.org/api/Printf.html) module and especially the conversion specifications for `printf` (the same as for `fprintf`).

To print a bool you just need to write

```ml
Printf.printf "%B"
```

[EDIT] Don't use `%b`, it's deprecated